# Make a new container with a combination of two separate containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, jenkins-docker

I want a container which have both, docker application and jenkins application installed.
I have tried building a new container from a Dockerfile -
`
FROM :docker
FROM :jenkins/jenkins

but it only seems to have jenkins but no docker .
`

Comment: Can you tell us how this is related to programming? You are at the wrong site!

Comment: You probably need to create an image `FROM jenkins/jenkins` that uses the native package-management tools to install the `docker` client binary.  You can't combine images the way you propose.

Answer (score 0):

That's not good practice if you want really to do that.
And if answer is still yes then you should pick docker image that suits both needs like ubuntu (of course search for smallest possible version) or something.

If answer is no then create two separate containers.